# Algebraically find the fundamental period of a $\cos^2(2\pi t)$?

Tags: trigonometry, signal-processing, periodic-functions

How do I find algebraically the fundamental period $T$ of $\cos^2(2\pi t) $? I understand that the condition for periodicity is $x(t) = x(t+T)$ and that $\ \omega=2\pi f ={2 \pi \over T} $ but I don't know how to get the period of the sinusoid without graphing it.

Comment: It helps to know what the period of $\cos^2$ is, because then it's just a rescaling.

Comment: And thats my issue. How do I algebraically derive the period of cos square?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "algebraically" derive. To start with, you presumably know that $\cos$ has period $2\pi$, so the period of $\cos^2$ is $2\pi/k$ for some integer $k$. Then it helps to know that $\cos(x+\pi) = -\cos(x)$, a special case of the angle addition formula. From that, you know $\cos^2(x+\pi) = \cos^2(x)$. Then you just need to show that the period can't be smaller than $\pi$; for example, $\cos^2(0)=\cos^2(\pi) = 1$, but there is no $x \in (0, \pi)$ with $\cos^2(x)=1$.

Comment: I mean that I could use software and graph it and quickly find out what the period is

Comment: I'm not familiar with any cut and dry rules for deriving the period, unless the function you are given is of the form $Af(Bx+C)+D$ where $f$ is a function with a known period. You just have to be comfortable enough with the definition and using it to prove that a function has a given period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up realizing that the easiest way to go about it would be to convert the $ cos^2(2\pi t) $ into a term without a square via the double angle formulas, so that it would turn into $ 1 \over 2  $ * $ cos(4\pi t) $ and some constant. Using the angular frequency formula above, the period then is 0.5s.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

from 
$$
\cos^2(x+T)=\cos^2 x
$$

we have:

$$
\cos (x+T)= \cos x \quad \lor \quad \cos (x+T)=-\cos x
$$

so $T=k\pi$.  In your equation : $x=2\pi t$ and you want ( for $k=1$) $x+\pi=2\pi(t+\tau)$ where $\tau$ is the perion ( in variable $t$). Substitute and find $\tau$.